# Why am I getting error: null value in column when inserting into a table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two tables in postgresql, as follows:

**User Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass),
    first_name character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email citext COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_password character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    business_status boolean NOT NULL,
    phone_number character varying(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bt_id integer,
    bs_id integer,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_verified boolean NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT users_email_key UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT bs_id FOREIGN KEY (bs_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_step (bs_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT bt_id FOREIGN KEY (bt_id)
        REFERENCES public.business_type (bt_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID
)
```

**Admin Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.admin
(
    admin_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('admin_admin_id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT admin_pkey PRIMARY KEY (admin_id),
    CONSTRAINT user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I am using Nodejs to implement a route in which I can insert a new administrator with the following code:

**Code in Queries.js**

```
const insertAdmin = (request, response) => {
    const { user_id } = request.body

    pool.query('INSERT INTO admin (user_id) VALUES ($1)', [user_id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${result.insertId}`)
    })
}
```

**Code in index.js**

```
app.post('/admins/insert', db.insertAdmin)
```

When inserting a new administrator using the following curl route:

```
curl --data "user_id =39" http://localhost:3000/users
```

I am getting the following error message:

> error: null value in column "user_id" of relation "admin" violates not-null constraint
> at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\ealfo\node-api-postgres\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
> at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\ealfo\node-api-postgres\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
> at Parser.parse (C:\Users\ealfo\node-api-postgres\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
> at Socket. (C:\Users\ealfo\node-api-postgres\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:10:42)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
> length: 265,
> severity: 'ERROR',
> code: '23502',
> detail: 'Failing row contains (12, null).',
> hint: undefined,
> position: undefined,
> internalPosition: undefined,
> internalQuery: undefined,
> where: undefined,
> schema: 'public',
> table: 'admin',
> column: 'user_id',
> dataType: undefined,
> constraint: undefined,
> file: 'd:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\executor\execmain.c',
> line: '1965',
> routine: 'ExecConstraints'
> }

Why does this error message appears? I am new at using NodeJS and PostgreSQL, I apologize if this question has been answered in another post. Nonetheless, I would like to learn more and learn from my mistakes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, `user_id` must be NULL.

Comment: No, user_id is not NULL.

Comment: Then you cannot get that error.

Comment: That's the whole point of this post. I shouldn't be getting this error but its still giving me the error.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add body-parser to your middleWare. Judging by the curl command you will need to parse the body from url.

Something like.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to pass bodies from url
```

Full documentation of body-parser library can be found: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Also remove the space after user_id. i.e curl --data "user_id =39" http://localhost:3000/users should be curl --data "user_id=39" http://localhost:3000/users